# Propagating Scope Events from a Factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory, angularjs-rootscope

### Neither $rootScope.$broadcast nor $rootScope.$emit is working from my factory

I have `$rootScope` injected into the factory. The factory returns this function:

```
alertHook: function() {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('getRollups', 'finally');
}
```

I injected that factory into a directive and call the `alertHook()` function.

I am listening for `getRollups` like so:

```
$scope.$on( 'getRollups', function( evt, args ) {
    console.log( args );
  });
```

Lo and behold, nothing is logged to the console. I've also tried $emit instead of $broadcast.

Help please, before I go insane :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With factories use [`$rootScope.$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast):

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.factory("factory", function($rootScope) {
   return { broadcast: broadcast };
   function broadcast () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("myEvent","from factory")
   }
})
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,factory) {
  $scope.$on("myEvent", function(ev,args) {
    console.log(ev.name,args);
  });
  $scope.clickMe = function() {
    factory.broadcast();
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button ng-click="clickMe()">Click me</button>
</body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Event Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation)
- [AngularJS $rootScope Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

Comment: I may not be understanding, but isn't that what I'm doing? Do you need me to explain the situation a little better?

Comment: Ahhh ok i see what you're saying, and it worked. Thank you. I'm guessing the way i had it, the function was never executing?

Comment: Now, how can I call that service from the directive when the directive loads?

Comment: One common problem with event propagation is that events fired before an event handler is added are not seen by that event handler. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem.** See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).